# Type agnostic channels in go

Tags: interface, go, channel

I'm still sort of wrapping my head around interfaces within golang. Is it possible to send multiple different types over a single, "generic" channel?

Here's a very simple example: http://play.golang.org/p/7p2Bd6b0QT.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/x_fgdhv-4EP A bit late but modified your code so it actually works. I wouldn't write it like that though.

Comment: @slaxor how is 5 years "a bit" late? :D

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. For example in your code you could just use:

```
greet: make(chan pet)
```

And then you would be able to send seamlessly anything that implements `type pet interface`.

If you want to send something *completely* generic you can use a `chan interface{}` and then use `reflect` to find out what it is when you receive something.

---

A dumb - and probably not idiomatic - example:

```
ch := make(chan interface{})

go func() {
    select {
    case p := <-ch:
        fmt.Printf("Received a %q", reflect.TypeOf(p).Name())
    }
}() 
ch <- "this is it"
```

---

As BurntSushi5 points out, a type switch is better:

```
p := <-ch
switch p := p.(type) {
case string:
    fmt.Printf("Got a string %q", p)
default:
    fmt.Printf("Type of p is %T. Value %v", p, p)
}
```

Comment: I think in general, you'll want to use a type switch before resorting to reflection. To get the type name, you can use the formatting option %T with the value. No `reflect` needed.