# Monitor fullness of any channel in Go

Tags: go, generics, channel

There are several channels to monitor, their type are different and irrelevant(since we only care about len and cap), but golang compiler does not accept following code, whatever T is:

```
func monitorChan(ch chan T) {
    for {
        if len(ch) == cap(ch) {
            log.Warn("log")
        }
        time.Sleep(chanMonitorInterval)
    }
}
```

it shows error:

> cannot use ch (type chan []byte) as type chan interface {} in argument
>   to monitorChan.

How can this function be modified to write once monitor every channel?

---

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func monitorChan(ch chan interface{}) {
    for {
        if len(ch) == cap(ch) {
            fmt.Println("log")
        }
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan []byte, 100)
    go monitorChan(ch)
    // actual things below ...
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/t7T28IpLNAs

Comment: Please post your code where you are calling the function with appropriate arguments and their types to recreate the error you are facing

Comment: here's the code: https://play.golang.org/p/t7T28IpLNAs

Comment: Have a look here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/22083490/type-agnostic-channels-in-go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083490/type-agnostic-channels-in-go)

Comment: Wrap around `chan interface{}` does work, but I would like channels with explicit types in source code, messages are preferred to be consumed without type casting

Comment: What motivates this code?  If you try to write to a full channel, Go will automatically block this goroutine, resume another, and resume this goroutine when it's possible for the write to complete.  You don't need to take any manual action to "allow another thread to run while you're waiting", which is what this code feels like to me.

Comment: @DavidMaze because the channel length depends on both external data and consumer, I want a buffered one to prevent blocking receiving

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use reflection. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "reflect"
    "time"
)

func monitorChan(ch interface{}, intvl time.Duration) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(ch)
    if v.Kind() != reflect.Chan {
        return
    }

    c := v.Cap()
    if c == 0 {
        return
    }
    for {
        if l := v.Len(); l == c {
            log.Printf("log: len(%d) cap(%d)", l, c)
        }
        time.Sleep(intvl)
    }
}

func main() {
    log.Print("main")
    c := make(chan []byte, 10)
    var chanMonitorInterval = 1 * time.Second
    go monitorChan(c, chanMonitorInterval)
    log.Print("monitor")

    time.Sleep(5 * chanMonitorInterval)
    for len(c) != cap(c) {
        c <- []byte{}
    }
    log.Print("len(c) == cap(c)")
    time.Sleep(3 * chanMonitorInterval)
    <-c
    log.Print("len(c) < cap(c)")
    time.Sleep(5 * chanMonitorInterval)
    log.Print("main")
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/c5VhIIO0pik

Output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 main
2009/11/10 23:00:00 monitor
2009/11/10 23:00:05 len(c) == cap(c)
2009/11/10 23:00:06 log: len(10) cap(10)
2009/11/10 23:00:07 log: len(10) cap(10)
2009/11/10 23:00:08 log: len(10) cap(10)
2009/11/10 23:00:08 len(c) < cap(c)
2009/11/10 23:00:13 main
```

---

References:

[Package reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)

[The Go Blog: The Laws of Reflection](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection)

Answer (score 2):

#### Go 1.18

This is now trivial to accomplish, using type parameters:

```
func monitorChan[T any](ch chan T) {
    for {
        if len(ch) == cap(ch) {
            log.Warn("log")
        }
        time.Sleep(chanMonitorInterval)
    }
}
```

Type inference also allows to infer the type parameter `T` from the concrete type of the function argument, so the code in `main` doesn't even need to be rewritten:

```
func main() {
    ch := make(chan []byte, 100)
    go monitorChan(ch) // T instantiated as []byte
    // actual things below ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create an `interface{}` type channel and pass any type wrapping around `interface{}`, then fetch the use type assert on receiving end.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func monitorChan(ch chan interface{}) {
    val := <-ch
    fmt.Println(string(val.(interface{}).([]uint8)))
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan interface{}, 100)
    wg.Add(1)
    ch <- []byte("hello")
    go monitorChan(ch)
    wg.Wait()
    // actual things below ...
}
```

Working code on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qLK-E9kDLac)

**Edited** :- you can also go for reflect package to get the values of channels after wrapping the channels inside `interface{}`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "reflect"
)

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func monitorChan(i interface{}) {
    defer wg.Done()
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    fmt.Printf("%s size: %d/%d\n", v.Kind(), v.Len(), v.Cap())
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan []byte, 100)
    wg.Add(1)
    go monitorChan(ch)
    wg.Wait()
    // actual things below ...
}
```

[Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/spI0Ed3Wcou)