# cannot use make(IntChannel) (value of type IntChannel) as Consumer value in variable declaration

Tags: go, channel

We have a below scenario:

```
package main

type Consumer chan interface {
    OpenChannel()
    CloseChannel()
}

type IntChannel chan int
type StringChannel chan string

func (c IntChannel) OpenChannel() {

}

func (c IntChannel) CloseChannel() {

}

func (c StringChannel) OpenChannel() {

}

func (c StringChannel) CloseChannel() {

}

func main() {

    var dataChannel Consumer = make(IntChannel)
    for data = range dataChannel {

    }
}
```

---

Goal is to `range` on  `dataChannel`.

`var dataChannel Consumer = make(IntChannel)` gives error: `cannot use make(IntChannel) (value of type IntChannel) as Consumer value in variable declaration`

We pick int channel or string channel based on a given config value at runtime.

Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22083490/3317808), but not much help.

---

How to range on a channel type that picks either int data or string data?

Comment: Go's type system has no co/contravariance. You cannot do what you want. You have to decide on the channel type. Like having an EitherStringOrInt type and use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you declared `Consumer` as a `chan` of `interface{ /* methods */ }`, which most surely isn't what you want — as a matter of fact, the error tells that you can't assign `IntChannel` to it.

Then, until generics are added to the language, you don't have a way to preserve type safety.

The closest solution to what you want to do might be adding an additional method to the interface that returns something that you can `range` over.

```
type Consumer interface {
    OpenChannel()
    CloseChannel()
    Range() <-chan interface{}
}

type IntChannel chan int

func (c IntChannel) OpenChannel() {
}

func (c IntChannel) CloseChannel() {
}

func (c IntChannel) Range() <-chan interface{} {
    ret := make(chan interface{})
    go func() {
        defer close(ret)
        for v := range c {
            ret <- v
        }
    }()
    return ret
}

func main() {
    c := make(IntChannel)
    var dataChannel Consumer = c
    go func() {
        c <- 12
        close(c)
    }()
    for data := range dataChannel.Range() {
        fmt.Println(data)
    }
}
```

Go1 Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/55BpISRVadE

---

With generics (Go 1.18, early 2022), instead you can just define a parametrized type with underlying type `chan`:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type GenericChan[T] chan T

func main() {
    c := make(GenericChan[int])
    go func() {
        c <- 12
        close(c)
    }()
    for data := range c {
        fmt.Println(data)
    }
}
```

Go2 Playground: https://go2goplay.golang.org/p/HQJ36ego97i

Comment: But in line `fmt.Println(data)` how do I interpret the type of `data` before processing it? that `int` can be any user defined type

Comment: @overexchange you can use a type switch. `switch t := data.(type) { ... }`. This can  cover builtin types. If someone may supply literally any type at all, including defined types, you should probably require those types to implement an interface that you can switch on.