# go function that accepts any channel

Tags: go, channel

I would like to write a function in go that takes a generic channel as an input. I'd like it to be able to accept any channel regardless of what type that channel is for. I assumed I could us `func myFunc(channel chan interface{})` but I'm getting a compilation error when I try to pass my channel to it. Is there a way to do this in go?

---EDIT---

I've been asked for a minimal working example, so I thought I'd share some code below. What I would like is something along the lines of

```golang
package main

func SendToChannel(arg interface{}, channel chan interface{}) error {
    channel<-arg
    //more logic here, potentially returning errors if something goes wrong
    return nil  
}


func main() {
    IntChan := make(chan int)
    StringChan := make(chan string)
    SendToChannel(1,IntChan)
    SendToChannel("hello",StringChan)
}
```

However, this gives a compilation error because, as Kelsnare pointed out, `chan int`, `chan string` and `chan interface{}` are three completely different types.

It seems likely that this will not be possible to achieve until generics come out in 2022, but if anyone has discovered a workaround I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Right now, with Go `1.17` and below, you have to do: `myFunc(channel interface{})`. Next year, with Go `1.18` you should be able to do: `myFunc(channel chan T)`. If you interested you can read the [Channels](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#channels) section of the proposal.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68996854/965900

Comment: Please provide details of  the compilation error you meet and some related code, to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for reference.

Answer (score 3):

`chan interface{}` and `chan int` are two distinct type definitions.

Consider this example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func myFunc(ch chan interface{}) {
    fmt.Println("I'm called")
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    myFunc(ch)
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

This function panics with

```
cannot use ch (type chan int) as type chan interface {} in argument to myFunc
```

Let's change the type to `chan interface{}`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func myFunc(ch chan interface{}) {
    fmt.Println("I'm called")
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan interface{})
    myFunc(ch)
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

This compiles.

`chan int` is used as an example - anything else apart from `chan interface{}` as the type for `ch` will result in a panic.

If you absolutely want a function that you want to be able to call with any of `chan int`, `chan string`, `chan customtype` your only bet right now is to accept a plain `interface{}`.

As @mkopriva mentioned though, generics are coming soon.